# Тавтология и плеоназм

Tags: терминология

Не могу до конца разобраться в соотношении терминов "тавтология" и "плеоназм". Являются ли они близкими, но разными понятиями или одно входит в другое? В последнем случае какое более широкое?

Словари дают разный ответ на этот вопрос. Если кто-то хорошо знает эти понятия - не могли бы вы показать их различие не примерах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На примерах. Тавтология:  масло масленое, станцевать танец.
Плеоназм: сувенир на память (сувенир - это и есть подарок на память), моя автобиография.
Как говорится, почувствуйте разницу.
Ваше затруднение вполне понятно. Понятия очень близкие. В теории, действительно, единства нет. Вы в своем вопросе основные версии изложили. Начнешь читать - точно запутаешься. Потому что переходных явлений, которые можно было бы оценить двояко, много. При тавтологии - обычно однокоренные слова. При плеоназме - смысловой повтор. Начинаешь сравнивать примеры, получается. что смысловая избыточность - в обоих случаях. Мне больше нравится версия о том, что тавтология - вид плеоназма. (Хочется сравнить: как синекдоха - вид метонимии).

Comment: В интернете эти понятия трактуются шире. Впрочем, это касается плеоназма/тавтологии как стилистического приема. Если же рассматривать понятие уже - только как ошибку - то, действительно, тавтологию можно считать разновидностью плеоназма.  

Кстати, я считаю, что плеоназмы типа "памятный сувенир", "прейскурант цен" и т.п. можно было бы считать нормой. Как, например, "экспонат выставки". Ведь их тавтологичность возникает только при переводе иностранного слова на русский. Для носителя языка-приемника точный смысл таких слов затемнен, т.е. они приобретают в русском фактически __другой смысл__.

Comment: Возможно, так и будет.

Comment: С прейскурантом - вряд ли. Сейчас в моде прайс-лист. Сочетания "прайс-лист цен" я что-то не слышала! ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Плеоназм это смысловая избыточность, тавтология это повторение однокоренных слов.

```
Другая другая возможность
```

Это тавтология, но не плеоназм.

```
Другая возможность-альтернатива
```

Это плеоназм, но не тавтология.

```
Самый лучший фильм
```

Это не плеоназм и не тавтология, так как является логической ошибкой - не бывает самых лучших. Тем не менее в языке это устоявшийся речевой оборот. Не знаю принятого термина для таких оборотов.